# node.js what is causing error 400 bad request

Tags: node.js, express, http, caching, http-error

I was adding some code to my node.js web app. I added this one feature, and then it threw an error 400. I removed it by hitting Ctrl-Z, but it still threw error 400. Then, I made a test.js that was the simplest implementation of express, and it is still getting error 400. Here is my code for test.js:

```
const app = require("express")();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const url = require('url');

app.get("/", function(req, res)
{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/test.html");
});

http.listen(3001, function()
{
    console.log("--listening on port 3001");
});
```

I have checked to make sure I am typing in the correct url, with the correct port. I think something got cached and is screwing it up, since it works if I clear my cache or use curl. Any ideas?

Comment: To confirm/eliminate caching, have you tried on a different browser? Try making the request from the command line (e.g. `curl http://localhost:3001/`)

Comment: I just tried the curl command. It works as expected. It definitely is caching that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use process.cwd() instead of __dirname which is causing error and generating 404.
process.cwd() will return the directory where node is intialized. It returns absolute path where you started the node.js process.

```
const app = require("express")();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

app.get("/", function(req, res)
{
    //  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/test.html");
    res.sendFile(process.cwd() + "/test.html");
});

http.listen(3001, function()
{
    console.log("--listening on port 3001");
});
```

or You can also resolve the path of __dirname

```
const app = require("express")();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

app.get("/", function(req, res)
{
    __dirname=path.resolve();  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/test.html");

});

http.listen(3001, function()
{
    console.log("--listening on port 3001");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more research (and thanks to comments), I finally found the problem!
I was storing too much stuff in cookies, and it exceeded the maximum amount of 4KB.